# Floating Action Button and EditText Problem

Tags: android

I have some problems with my android studio.

About 2 days ago, my floating button shows add icon(+) and works perfectly fine.

Last night when I opened android studio, icon didn't appear. It only showed background.

Another problem is EditText.
It doesn't appear on Design.

When I open another project, I am facing with the same problem. I can't see EditText.

Please tell me how I can fix them.**strong text***strong text*

Comment: Sync the Gradle and then Rebuild the project from the build menu.

Comment: Please add your code snippet here or maybe this issue is related to you IDE. indicate what version you are using to be more clear :)

Answer (score 0):

Try these. They may helps :

1. Invalidate caches and restart.
   2.Change theme in res>themes both to AppCompat
   3.Sync the Gradle and rebuild project.
   4.Check be sure there is no problem with your code